# GDB to debug OpenCV in ROS

Tags: c++, opencv, gdb, ros

I used OpenCV in my ROS codebase. I saw a segmentation fault in a function in OpenCV. It may not be a problem in OpenCV, but it'll be helpful for me to debug if I know what exactly the error is.

However, the symbol table is not available:

```
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007ffff633eefe in CvANN_MLP::predict(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&) const () from /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libopencv_ml.so.2.4
No symbol table info available.
```

I have linked OpenCV in the CMakeList.txt.

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(agentlib debug ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Answer (score 1):

If You installed OpenCV and ROS form packages, try to also install -dbg packages. If You built the libraries on Your own, try building them in debug configuration. To set debug version for a CMake project You need to set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable to `Debug`.

Answer (score 0):

Combination `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RelWithDebInfo -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG` successfully appends debug information.